# How to access the style that was applied to previous/above cell in context of the current cell in Aggrid React?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

Lets assume i have applied cellStyle to all the cells.

```
cellStyle: params => getCellStyle(params)

const getCellStyle = (params) => {
return { borderBottom : '2px solid black'} 
}
```

How do i access these style attributes of once cell from another cell?